# Please list some well tested api's for arima model

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, time-series

I am looking for a good python api for timeseries models such as ARIMA. Please list some well tested apis and few more advance models possible for financial time-series analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Statsmodels:**

[Statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/) is your best bet for a python library that includes ARIMA.  I have used it fairly extensively and am quite happy with it. But, its certainly not as well tested as R based ARIMA models.

**R:**

If you want something "well-tested" then your best bet is likely to use [Rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) to call an [R](https://cran.r-project.org/) based [ARIMA library](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html) from python. Rpy2 can be a bit tricky based on version reconciliation between python, R and Rpy2.

Here's a [turorial on calling R from python using Rpy2](https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It was really helpful.